# jqgrid remove selected row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I add/remove rowdata in grid   by code.

Add:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "MyHandler.ashx?......",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
            var serverData = JSON.parse(data);
            var newRowData = [{
                "IAnsDateTime": serverData.ServerDate,
                "ID": serverData.ID,
                "IAnsState": $('#comboLastStatus').find(":selected").text(),
            }];
           gridParaf.addRowData(serverData.ID, newRowData, 'first');
```

When data add in sql then rowdata add in grid its work fine and when user remove row of grid if data remove success on sql then must be remove on grid.

Remove:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "Handler1.ashx?...............",
    type: "POST",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == "True") {
            gridParaf.delRowData(selectedrow["ID"]);

        }
        else {

        }
```

Data remove on sql but "gridParaf.delRowData(selectedrow["id"])" not work and data still show on grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in alert that selectedrow["id"] show id or not . May be undefined value come in delRowData() method.

Comment: If you row delete from database side so after success message of data you can direct refresh grid using gridParaf.trigger( 'reloadGrid' );

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gridParaf.delRowData(selectedrow["ID"]);

$("#delmod"+gridParaf[0].id).hide();

if (gridParaf[0].p.lastpage > 1) {
     gridParaf.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page:gridParaf[0].p.page}]);
}
```

Comment: If i don't add row by code(just by reload grid),it's work fine and i can delete row by "gridParaf.delRowData"  but when add row by " gridParaf.addRowData" then "gridParaf.delRowData" not work

Comment: After delete and add row in JqGrid when you want to delete another row it create problem because it index was not Updated and they are not getting found any id to delete it. To overcome this problem you still to refresh index of Grid using Upper code.